# Content under fixed header and navbar when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want the header and navbar to be fixed when scrolling on my site. I can make these both fixed, however the content in the #container div doesn't appear under them.

I currently use the following to make the content of my site appear below the header but not sure how to calculate the margintop for the #header AND #navbar ids.

```
#header{
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
}

#navbar{
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    margin:auto;
    position:fixed;
    top:120px;
}


$(document).ready(function () {
                    $('#container').css('marginTop', $('#header').outerHeight(true) );

                });
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you set up a jsfiddle.

Comment: managed to figure it out:

$(document).ready(function () {
                $('#container').css('marginTop', $('#header').outerHeight(true) + $('#navbar').outerHeight(true) );
                
            });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $(document).ready(function () { $('#container').css('marginTop', $('#header').outerHeight(true) + $('#navbar').outerHeight(true) ); });
```